# DJANGO media images not showing

Tags: python, django, django-media

Hello I am trying to display an image from
media/images

On my html I have this code:
index.html

```
 {% extends 'basic_app/base.html' %}

{% block metablock %}
<title>CBV - Index</title>
{% endblock metablock %}

{% block bodyblock %}
<div class="container-fluid">
    <h1>Hello {{word}}</h1>
    <img src="/media/images/bobcatminer.jpg" alt="bobcat">
</div>
{% endblock bodyblock %}
```

on settings.py I have this for media

```
MEDIA_ROOT = Path.joinpath(BASE_DIR,'media')
MEDIA_URL = '/media/'
```

I do not know what is going wrong, please help. Thanks beforehand.

Comment: this only works with debug = true, do you have debug = true ??

Comment: Did you add `MEDIA_ROOT` in your `project's url` and `app url` ?

Comment: try this `src="images/bobcatminer.jpg"`

Answer (score 2):

Add `MEDIA_ROOT` in your `project's url` and `app url`. Like this :-

In your app's urls (at the end) :-

```
]

urlpatterns += static(settings.STATIC_URL, document_root=settings.STATIC_ROOT)
urlpatterns += static(settings.MEDIA_URL, document_root=settings.MEDIA_ROOT)
```

In your project's url (at the end) :-

```
] + static(settings.MEDIA_URL, document_root=settings.MEDIA_ROOT)
```